# Set image in an input value

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I am trying to include an img tag inside an input's value attribute. I would like something like this using jquery:

```
<input type="text" value="Lorem Impsum <img src='...'/>" />
```

I already tried this:

```
jQuery(document).ready(function() { 
     productinput = jQuery('input[value=product]');
     productinput.val(data.selectedData.value + '<img style="width:128px" src="' + data.selectedData.imageSrc + '" />');
});
```

but it's not working. So, does anyone know how I can do this?

Note: it is an image inside the value.

Comment: why do you need to use image like this?

Comment: I would say that's not valid HTML?

Comment: The `img` tag would not be parsed, **it's a string in this context**. So unless you want to send this input's value to server and save it somewhere, you can't do this

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can set the image by putting image as the background of the element

For example

html

```
<input type="text" value="Lorem Impsum" class="default" />
```

css

```
input.default{
       background: url('../images/any.jpg') 0 0 no-repeat;
    }
```

You can set the css of the element using jquery on document ready.

Answer (score 1):

You should set the type to image.

```
<input type="image" name="image" src="image.png" width="50">
```

Try to read doc: [Mozilla documentation input/image](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/input/image)

Answer (score 0):

Try using the attribute "contenteditable" on a div

```
<div contenteditable> Lorem ipsum.. <img src='..'> </div>
```